# Change background color and show/hide on same click - Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to create a plugin with the design below; when a date is clicked on the background color of the div changes to purple and the css triangle also changes to purple, and also the post with the event information for the clicked date appears (or comes to the top). By default there should be one of the date boxes which is purple at the start, and its event post should be visible also. Obviously I would like the other date boxes to return to their original color when another date box is clicked.

Here is the link to view the design: http://www.flickr.com/photos/54875551@N05/5662143061/in/photostream.

I have tried to use the following to create the background color change on click, but it is not working for the css triangle as well.

```
var highlightLink = function () {
var active = null, colour = '#97558b';
    if (this.attachEvent) this.attachEvent('onunload', function () {
    active = null;
});
return function (element) {
    if ((active != element) && element.style) {
    if (active) active.style.backgroundColor = '';
    element.style.backgroundColor = colour;
    active = element;
}
};
}();
```

and

```
 <div id="datebox1" class="date" onclick="highlightLink(this);">                                    
    <h1>MAY</h1>
    <h1 class="num">14</h1>                                          
    <div class="date-tri" onclick="highlightLink(this);"></div>
 </div>
```

So not only am I at a loss for how to add the css triangle into the onclick action, but I don't know how to coordinate that with the event posts (which are called seperately from the dateboxes in my php), like below:

```
<div id="event1" class="event">
    <h2 class="eventtitle">Brainerd Spring Arts &#038; Crafts Festival</h2>
    <div id="summary">
        <p>150+ artists/crafters with quality handmade items! 9:30-4 pm Brai High School. </p>
    </div>               
    <div class="link">
        <a href=""><p>http://www.excelsiorartonthelake.com</p></a>
    </div>                                              
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have the HTML + CSS anywhere? That would make it easier to write a JS (+HTML+CSS) fix.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't assign styles with Javascript. I say you never should ever ever, but some would disagree.

What I would do, is add/remove/toggle css classes on nodes. With css classes, you can style the way you style everything: in a stylesheet, readable, extendable.

So try something like this:

```
<div id="datebox1" class="date">                                    
    <h1>MAY</h1>
    <h1 class="num">14</h1>                                          
    <div class="date-tri"></div>
</div>
<div id="datebox2" class="date">                                    
    <h1>MAY</h1>
    <h1 class="num">18</h1>                                          
    <div class="date-tri"></div>
</div>

<script>
var active = null;
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.date')).forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (this !== active) {
            if ( active ) {
                active.classList.remove('active');
            }
            this.classList.add('active');
            active = this;
        }
    }, false);
});
</script>
```

Or see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/349Vr/

**PS**
I use `.addEventListener` and `.classList` as modern browser have. It looks like you're using a library (I see a `.attachEvent`)...

If you can use jQuery: that would make it a lot easier. Loop and attach events:

```
$('div.date').click(function(e) {
```

Add/remove class:

```
$(active).removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Comment: I'd like to give you an extra +1 for "you never should ever ever"

Comment: What? That's good Inglish it is! =p And I much agree with Rudie. Sounds like a smart people.

Comment: I'm just saying I agree with the statement and also agree with emphasizing it by using Never Ever Ever.